# What is wrong with my solution to the Monty Hall problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, puzzle, monty-hall

I'm trying to develop an intuitive sense of why the suggestion of the Monty Hall problem is that you should switch doors when an informed host opens one of the two dummy doors.

So, I'm trying to think of this without using any formulas or rigorous proofs by breaking the problem down into three steps:

1. the first choice of door
2. the door opened
3. the final choice of door

And just tabulating how many times a switch results in a win, and how many times a nonswitch results in a win. This is the result:

| Car | Goat | Goat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S |  |  |
|  | O |  |
|  |  | S |

| Car | Goat | Goat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S |  |  |
|  | O |  |
| S |  |  |

| Car | Goat | Goat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S |  |  |
|  |  | O |
|  | S |  |

| Car | Goat | Goat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S |  |  |
|  |  | O |
| S |  |  |

| Car | Goat | Goat |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | S |  |
|  |  | O |
| S |  |  |

| Car | Goat | Goat |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | S |  |
|  |  | O |
|  | S |  |

| Car | Goat | Goat |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | S |
|  | O |  |
| S |  |  |

| Car | Goat | Goat |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | S |
|  | O |  |
|  |  | S |

This is all eight outcomes that satisfy the condition:

1. the participant can choose any of the three doors originally at random
2. the host can only subsequently open a door that the participant did not choose
3. the host can only subsequently open a door that hides a goat
4. the participant is free to choose either of the remaining doors

From counting the results we see that there are four scenarios in which switching the door will result in a win, and four scenarios in which not switching the door will result in a win.

I am not debating what the correct answer to this problem is. I know that the correct answer has been both proven and demonstrated by simulation, and that the solution states that you double your chances of winning by choosing to switch doors. I simply seek to understand what is wrong about my assumptions that's leading me astray. Thanks!

Comment: But are your $8$ scenarios equally likely?  In your analysis, "First choice is the car" is true in 4 out of 8 cases?

Comment: Your table is not very clear. At the beginning there is obviously a chance of $\frac{2}{3}$ that you chose a door with a goat. So with probability $\frac{2}{3}$ you should switch.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the table entries mean in your eight cases. I suspect that your problem is that the cases correctly exhaust the possibilities but that you are assuming incorrectly that they are equally likely. Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake; it should have been four. I will edit now

Comment: I did not closely read your argument, but I assume it went something of the following: "There are eight scenarios, four result in the desired outcome when switching."  Do remember that the probability of something happening is not necessarily the number of good outcomes over the total number of outcomes.  There are two possibilities when playing the lottery, you either win or you lose, half of the outcomes are you winning but that is not equivalent to winning with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.  This calculation of "good over all" is only valid if outcomes are known to be equally likely.

Comment: As Mark remarks, 4 out of 8 is still wrong.

Comment: 1. Can you edit your 8 tables again? 2. What do the rows mean? 3. Why do your tables have 2 S's? 4. What does S mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first four scenarios each have probability $\frac13\times \frac12 \times \frac12 =\frac1{12}$ if the decisions are random within the constraints

The last four scenarios each have probability $\frac13\times 1 \times \frac12 =\frac1{6}$ if the decisions are random within the constraints

So they are not equally likely, though combined they give a probability of winning the car of $\frac12$ for somebody who switches or not at random.

For a determined switcher, the first and third scenarios  each have probability $\frac13\times \frac12 \times 1 =\frac1{6}$, making the probability of not winning the car $\frac13$.  For the same determined switcher, the fifth and seventh scenarios  each have probability $\frac13\times 1 \times 1 =\frac1{3}$, making the probability of winning the car $\frac23$.

Comment: Note that one way you can easily verify that the eight outcomes are not equally likely is that in four of them the contestant picks the car on the first guess. That translates to a probability of $\frac12$ if all outcomes are equally likely. But there should be only a $\frac13$ chance to guess the correct door out of three with no prior clues.

Comment: **1.** You both appear to grok [erf-x](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/685099/erf-x)'s 8 charts, but I don't. Can you please edit them for the confused like me? **2.** Can you please elaborate the rational numbers in your calculation? Where do the 1/3 spring from? 1/2? 1?

Comment: Feel free to edit your answer, instead of replying as a comment.

Comment: @user - no.  This was 11 months ago, and was a particular attempt by *erf x* to understand the Monty Hall Problem.  There many others with the same tag if you want to approach the question a different way.  The key point here is that in some cases Monty has a choice as to which door to open and in others has a forced choice from the constraints in the scenario, and that makes a difference